# How to narrow API response type with generics and conditional types?

Tags: typescript

I am sending a request to an API endpoint and its response differs according to a field called `productType` in the response. For example, API can return following responses:

```json
// response 1
{
    productType: 'Product1',
    product: 'Some product information'
}

// response 2
{
    productType: 'Product2',
    product: {moreNestedFields: 'Some product information'}
}
```

I want to be able to run different logic (narrow the type) in my client code according to `productType`.

Here is my simplified attempt to do it:

```js
type Product = 'Product1' | 'Product2';
type MyResponse<TProduct extends Product> = {
  product: TProduct extends 'Product1' ? 'SomeType' : 'SomeOtherType';
  productType: TProduct;
};

function getResponse<T extends Product>() {
  // This is accually some fetch request
  return {} as MyResponse<T>;
}


const response = getResponse();

if (response.productType === 'Product1') {
   //  myProduct is not type narrowed?
   // I am expecting it to only have 'SomeType' but its type is <'SomeType' | 'SomeOtherType'>
  const myProduct = response.product;                      
  // do something with myProduct
} else {
  // ..
}
```

What am I missing? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not `type MyResponse = { product: 'SomeType', productType: 'Product1' } | { product: 'SomeOtherType', productType: 'Product2' }`, so it's a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)?

Comment: I simplified this response actually. There are more than two productTypes and lots more fields. Most of the fields are the same type across productType but some of them depend on the productType. I wouldn't want to define a different type for each productType and union over them. Isn't it possible to use generics in this case?

Comment: Define an interface with the common bits. Have the discriminated union extend the common bits with *only* the fields that differ based on the discriminant(s): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyIArgLYBG0+yVJAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiFACE4UZBAAekEABNGaTDjoISAcnQgIqujKYt2XHn2jwkyEQC9xUiLPkYseAiuSqwAd3TaCu0pRpQhrhgAJ4ADigAqsgAvOaiyAA+8RY8MGQgCGDAGsgwABQSJJEAlEoEwDDIhQB0CLExceqaqmVOBMgIGozoADYQNb3obLUyNVAQEXBg+QDMJWUA9IvIzKwgHATcdJXVEnUNTR5ebXTO3X0DQyP7Y2DoqMASEDL5AEwLyMt+1LRbhkA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) instead of generics.
Updated `MyResponse` type:

```
type Product = 'Product1' | 'Product2';
type MyResponse =
  | {
      productType: Extract<Product, 'Product1'>;
      product: 'SomeType';
    }
  | {
      productType: Extract<Product, 'Product2'>;
      product: 'SomeOtherType';
    };
```

Note: `Extract` is added for more type safety to avoid typos.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwoF4oHJ7LrACMuUAPngahgEy4DcAUKJFALIgBKEAzmAgB2vaFiZQKUAN7iJcsIhrAAKuAgAuKAFEAHsDgBDDAB5qRADRVFRUgD5mc+dYybcAZQQBbCKsiNZEgC+spQyjhIKhBi+Gtp6hiZmGJb4zsD09gFOUcCuHt4A8sAAFhBwMf6OgQxAA)

If you have common fields for all types of responses, you can have them in a separate type and intersect them with the union:

```
type CommonFields = {
  status: string;
};

type MyResponse = CommonFields &
  (
    | {
        productType: Extract<Product, 'Product1'>;
        product: 'SomeType';
      }
    | {
        productType: Extract<Product, 'Product2'>;
        product: 'SomeOtherType';
      }
  );
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYQQrW)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you check the comment I entered for @jonrsharpe. Do you have any response on that

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's going to be possible with generics. For the common fields why not just do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYQQrW)?

Comment: Seems like this is the way to go. Thanks.